# Remove ICONS from Applications

Tags: applications

I tried to install Microsoft Office in Wine; the install worked but all of the apps failed. I tried to remove in Wine, did not uninstall. I remove from the Terminal in the ./wine directory. The ICONS are still in the Applications Menu. How do I get rid of those?

Answer (score 2):

Those icons are .desktop files. You could search for them and delete them manually, but before you do that, install AppEditor from the AppCenter. That should allow you to delete, or at least hide, them from the Launcher menu.